# Automake makefile doesn't link properly

Tags: autotools, automake, lib

I am building a project with Automake and I want to link GLFW and GLEW to the project. My Makefile.am looks like this:

```
AUTOMAKE_OPTIONS = foreign subdir-objects
bin_PROGRAMS = game
game_SOURCES = src/main.cpp
game_CXXFLAGS =
game_LDFLAGS = $(glfw3_LIBS) $(glew_LIBS)
```

This does not compile as the libraries are listed first in the linking command:

```
$ make
...
g++   -g -O2 -lglfw -lGLEW -lGLU -lGL  -o game src/game-main.o
...
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to use `_LDADD` instead of `_LDFLAGS`.

Comment: Yes, that would be appropriate. Link libraries for a program go in `LDADD` or `prog_LDADD`.  A few other flags may go there too, most notably `-L` flags, though most of those can also go in `LDFLAGS` or `prog_LDFLAGS`, too.  These variables are distinguished from each other because they need to go at different places in the link command line.